# How To hook time function

Tags: c++, linux, windows, api

EveryOne. I have a project which call some func to get time such as

> time_t t = time(NULL);

```
#ifndef _WIN32
    timespec ts;
    if( -1 == clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts) )
        GenErrnoErr()
    return uint64( ( ((uint64)ts.tv_sec*1000 + (uint64)ts.tv_nsec/1000000) - m_uBaseTime ) * ms_dTimeRatio ) ;
#else
    LARGE_INTEGER uTime;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&uTime);
    return uint64(  ( uint64(uTime.QuadPart/CFrequency::Instance().Get().QuadPart) - m_uBaseTime ) * ms_dTimeRatio );
#endif
```

`

what I wana is to hook all this time func, without change the code exist. when it calls time(NULL) or other func, it returns the time i faked.

Comment: Which compiler and linker are you using? `gcc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way that this sort of thing is done is with the `--wrap` option to the linker. It works like this:

1. Write your replacement function, but instead of naming it `time(...)`, name it `__wrap_time(...)`;
2. In your replacement function, if you need to call the original `time()` function, actually call `__real_time()`;
3. When linking the program, add the following option: `--wrap=time`. This will make the linker link any other module's call to `time()` to `__wrap_time()`, and yet still allow the original `time()` function to be called via `__real_time()`.

Thus:

```
// Need this to satisfy the compiler
extern time_t __real_time(time_t *seconds);

time_t __wrap_time(time_t *seconds) {
    if (seconds==NULL) {
        return 0;
    } // if
    return __real_time(seconds)
} // __wrap_time(seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Detour the function in the process to your hook. You'll need to inject a dll to hook it, and add a jmp to your hook function address within the original functions epilogue. Some more info would help too...